# Issue with scheduling the container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: container1
    #restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    labels:
      ofelia.enabled: "true"
      ofelia.job-exec.app.schedule: "@every 30m"
      ofelia.job-exec.app.command: "/app/Final_DM_For_All_Clients.py"

  ofelia:
    image: mcuadros/ofelia:latest
    #restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - app
    command: daemon --docker
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:r
```

After the first run, the second job run does not happen in 30 mins and I am getting the
following error during the second run.

```
container1-ofelia-1  | 2022-05-24T22:59:02.037Z  common.go:121 ▶ ERROR [Job "app" (3d8aab0fe293)] Finished in "3.322350449s", failed: true, skipped: false, error: error creating exec: API error (409): Container 65f90ee04e25d1164d29ab911197d239873da3eafbc34823873d3ba2d791a0ad is not running
```

My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8 

#ADD Final_DM_For_All_Clients.py /
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install numpy 
RUN pip install datetime
RUN pip install uuid 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc unixodbc-dev 
RUN pip install pyodbc

# install SQL Server drivers
#RUN apt-get update \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list \
#        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
#        msodbcsql17


RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools

RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose



RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && apt-get install vim -y




COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD df_curr.csv .
ADD df_prev.csv .
ADD df_roster.csv .
ADD df.csv .
ADD manager_name.csv .
ADD name_data.csv .

EXPOSE 8080 

CMD python Final_DM_For_All_Clients.py
```

After the first run the container exits with code 0 indicating a successful run but on the second scheduled run i.e. at 1 hr, since the container is stopped, the scheduler is not able to run the script during the second run.

Comment: Is the container running when Ofelia does its thing? Could you run `docker ps` before that happens?

Comment: @EDG956 The container was running  for the first run but for the second in the schedule the container isn't running. Hence I am getting this error above. Can you please suggest me a way to fix it.

Comment: I'd tell you to check the logs of the container to see why it could have died. Another thing with containers is that if the process started by running the `entrypoint` finishes, the container finishes. If the process finished cleanly, you wouldn't see errors. Then you'd need to see how to keep your container running. You can post the relevant part of the Dockerfile as well and I might be able to help

Comment: @EDG956 I have added the Dockerfile to the question as well

Comment: Can you explain in the question what the python script does?

Comment: @EDG956 he has sufficient comments for his code snippet here to indicate what his script does. Hasn't he?

Comment: @bonCodigo I had not read the last paragraph and was still not clear whether the script ran a one-off task or a webserver that's supposed to run indefinitely. Kind of makes a difference and the information is not as obvious

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're using ofelia's `exec` job, which tries to `docker exec` into a running container, which fails.

What you are looking for is the `run` job which, according to the [docs](https://github.com/mcuadros/ofelia/blob/master/docs/jobs.md#job-run), either runs a new container or starts an existing one. So I believe you should change your labels definition like this:

```yaml
ofelia:
   ...  # Your configs

   labels: 
      ofelia.enabled: "true"
      ofelia.job-run.app.schedule: "@every 30m"
      ofelia.job-run.app.container: "container1"

   ...  # Your configs
```

The docs say you have to pass in the `container` parameter when trying to do a `docker start`. I am not sure how it plays when you run it for the first time, but I assume that `app` runs on its own the first time and later times `ofelia` starts the container again.

Comment: with above mentioned change, I am getting the following error: {container1-ofelia-1  | unable to start a empty scheduler.}

Comment: Try now, moving the labels to the ofelia container